# JTextField how to read in text

Tags: java

In my GUI.java class, I have the following function:

```
public void setChat(String text)
{
   chat.append(text);
}

public void getInput(String text)
{
   String read = input.getText();
}
```

I am trying to use my getInput() method to set a username I will be using for the rest of my code, but I just can't seem to read it in correctly from the TextField in my Client.java. I'm having a lot of trouble getting the original:

String username = gui.getInput();

(That certainly didn't work either). Can someone help me read in a TextField entry and assign it to my username String?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client
{      
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
   GUI gui = new GUI();
   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        //GUI gui = new GUI();
     }
  }); 

  String username = "";      
  gui.setChat("  Enter the username you would like to use for the duration of the chat session.\n");
  if (username == "")
  {
     System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
     new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
     gui.getInput(username);
     gui.setChat("  Your username is now: " + username + ".\n");
  }
 }
}
```

---

EDIT 1

GUI.java class:

```
String getInput(String text)
{
   return input.getText();
}
```

Client.java class:

```
  String username;
  gui.setChat("  Enter the username you would like to use for the duration of the chat session.\n");
  username = gui.getInput();

  System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
  new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
  gui.setChat("  Your username is now: " + username + ".\n");
```

Errors:

```
Client.java:19: error: method getInput in class GUI cannot be applied to given types;
  username = gui.getInput();
                ^
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: getInput() should return a String rather than having a String parameter. Then you can just use username = gui.getInput().

Comment: Whenever I try to return instead it gives me errors.

Comment: List the errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void getInput(){
    return input.getText();
}
```

then in the main

```
username = "" + gui.getInput();
```

Comment: Please include some explanations to your answer. that will help OP and other visitors.

Comment: No good. "GUI.java:95: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value".

Comment: It should be public String getInput() not public void getInput(), there will also be no need to add "" + since it will already be a string.

Comment: I changed getInput() to a String. I edited my post. It's giving me errors about the type though.

Comment: I noticed in your edit that you still have the getInput method asking for a string argument to be passed in, however when you call gui.getInput() you are not passing in a String. The string argument is actually unneeded and can be removed from the method.